# How insert header and footer in officejs from ooxml of full document

Tags: office365, office-js

From a doc file I am reading header of doc from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee413542(v=office.12).aspx reference. I am able to get the OOXML of header, but I am not able to insert it in my online word using office 365 add in.
Kindly help me to insert header from full document ooxml in online word.

Regards,
Praveen

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more. Is the header fixed or you want to insert text into any doc in which your add-in opened? Which method you tried calling?

Answer (score 0):

Found this sample that insert header in the word document

```
function insertHeader() {
    Word.run(function (context) {
        var myHeader = context.document.sections.getFirst()
            .getHeader("primary").insertText("This is a header", "start");
        return context.sync();
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}

    function insertFooter() {

    Word.run(function (ctx) {

        // Create a proxy collection for the sections collection.
        var mySections = ctx.document.sections;

        // Queue a command to load style property of the sections.
        ctx.load(mySections, 'body/style');

        // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands,
        // and returning a promise to indicate task completion.
        return ctx.sync().then(function () {

            // Get the primary footer of the first section and create
            // a proxy Body object for the footer.
            var myFooter = mySections.items[0].getFooter("primary");

            // Queue a command to insert a paragraph at the end of the footer.
            myFooter.insertParagraph("Confidential", "end");

            // Queue a command to insert a line break at the end of the footer. 
            myFooter.insertBreak("line", "end");
        })
        // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands.
        .then(ctx.sync)
        .then(function () {
            handleSuccess();
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            handleError(error);
        })
    });
}
```